# How to choose timeout parameters for particular webserver ANSI C

Tags: c, post, timeout, webserver

I plan to develop a Linux webapp to collect data from many people. The entered data should be first preprocessed using a service (some kind of numbers crunching), which is written entirely in ANSI C, then recorded in a database.

I am tempted to develop the whole webapp in ANSI C, I have some modules for this purpose. I am (I hope) enough disciplined programmer to deal with alloc, free, buffer overflow etc.

I have some questions about how to configure the implementation of the post method, url encoded variant.

1) Connection established

2) POST / HTTP/1.1

3) Host: ...

4) Content-length: ...

...

n) parm1=val1&parm2=val2...

How much reasonable time should I wait between (1) and (2) or, generally speaking, between (k) and (k+1) ? Ten seconds, or more ?

How many distinct recv's should I accept ? Two, three, more ? Depending on the total size of input (how) ?

Every request should be processed by a separate thread.

I wish to avoid (if it is possible) some slow loris attacks, and to accept users to use desktop or smart mobile devices.

Any kind of advices and / or documentations are welcome.

Comment: 21 seconds, but that is only half of the truth... ;) Srsly, these kind of questions are off-topic here, come back if you have a programming problem to solve

Comment: The maximum possible/necessary number of calls to [`recv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) is the number of `char`s to be transferred. `recv()` tells you how much it got. Just loop around it until you got all.

Comment: I'd say this is very platform-/network-/user-dependent and slightly off-topic. Consider your worst case scenario based on your desired throughput (if we could call it that) or performance. Nothing to be really worried about in a multi-threaded context, though.

Comment: What's "ANSI-C", C90? Why would you develop new programs in an obsolete dialect of C?